# How to compute the gradient of any loss function

Tags: derivatives, optimization, matrix-calculus, gradient-descent

I have the following loss function to minimize :
$\hat{\mathbf{A}} = \arg \min_{\mathbf{A}} \frac{1}{2}{\parallel{\mathbf{Y} - \mathbf{K}  \left(\left(  \mathbf{D}\mathbf{A}\right)\odot\mathbf{M}\right)}\parallel}_{F}^{2} + \frac{1}{2}{\parallel{\mathbf{W} - \mathbf{L}\left(\left(  \mathbf{D}\mathbf{A}\right)\odot\mathbf{H}\right) \mathbf{S}}\parallel}_{F}^{2}$

Where ${\parallel\mathbf{X}\parallel}_{F}^{2} =Tr(\mathbf{XX^T})$ is the Frobenius norm, and $\odot$ denote Hadamard product (element-wise product).

For the first term : $\mathbf{Y}\in\mathbb{C}^{a\times l}$,  $\mathbf{K}\in\mathbb{C}^{a\times b}$, $\mathbf{D}\in\mathbb{C}^{b\times d}$, $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{d\times l}$ and $\mathbf{M}\in\mathbb{C}^{b\times l}$.

For the second term : $\mathbf{W}\in\mathbb{C}^{b\times c}$,  $\mathbf{L}\in\mathbb{C}^{b\times b}$, $\mathbf{H}\in\mathbb{C}^{b\times l}$ and $\mathbf{S}\in\mathbb{C}^{l\times c}$.

I know when the loss function is on the form :

$J(X) = \frac{1}{2}{\parallel{\mathbf{Y} - \mathbf{K}  \left(  \mathbf{X}\odot\mathbf{M}\right)}\parallel}_{F}^{2}$

then its derivative is :

$\nabla J(X) = K^{H}\left( \mathbf{Y} - \mathbf{K}  \left(  \mathbf{X}\odot\mathbf{M}\right)\right)\odot \mathbf{M}$

But in this case it is so difficult. Is there any way to compute its gradiant ?

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\g{\gamma}\def\l{\lambda}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\FF#1{\left\|#1\right\|_F^2}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$For typing convenience, define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
B &= {H\odot\LR{DA}} &\qiq dB = {H\odot\LR{D\;dA}} \\
C &= {LBS-W} &\qiq dC = L\:dB\:S\\
}$$
and introduce the Frobenius product, which is a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \\&= \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$
Finally, the Frobenius and Hadamard products commute
$$\eqalign{
A:\LR{B\odot C}
 \,=\, \LR{A\odot B}:C
 \:=\: \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij} \\
\\
}$$

---

Use the above notation to rewrite the last term in your loss function. Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\a &= \tfrac 12\:{C:C} \\
d\a &= C:dC \\
 &= C:\LR{L\:dB\:S} \\
 &= \LR{L^TCS^T}:dB \\
 &= \LR{L^TCS^T}:\LR{H\odot\LR{D\;dA}} \\
 &= H\odot\LR{L^TCS^T}:\LR{D\;dA} \\
 &= D^T\LR{H\odot\LR{L^TCS^T}}:dA \\
\grad{\a}{A} &= D^T\LR{H\odot\LR{L^T\c{C}S^T}} \\
}$$
or, in terms of the original variables
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\a}{A}
 &= D^T\LR{H\odot\LR{L^T\CLR{L\LR{H\odot\LR{DA}}S-W}S^T}} \\
}$$
The calculation for the other half of the loss function is analogous, after substituting variables
$$\eqalign{
&\LR{\a,W,L,H,S} \to \LR{\b,Y,K,M,I} \\
&\grad{\b}{A} = D^T\LR{M\odot\LR{K^T\CLR{K\LR{M\odot\LR{DA}}-Y}}} \\
}$$
Since $S$ was replaced by an identity matrix, it has been completely omitted.

The full loss function is therefore
$$\eqalign{
\l &= \a + \b \qiq
\grad{\l}{A} &= \grad{\a}{A} + \grad{\b}{A} \\\\
}$$

### Update

The above derivation mistakenly used *real* matrices. *Complex* matrices necessitate the use of the [${\mathbb{CR}}$-calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.4835), also known as [Wirtinger derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives). The basic idea is to treat a variable and its complex conjugate as two **formally** independent variables.

Here is a simple example. $\,$ Let $X\in{\mathbb C}^{m\times n}\:$ and $X^*$ denote its complex conjugate, then
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= \FF{X} \;=\; X:X^* \\
d\phi &= X^*:dX \;+\; X:dX^* \\
\grad{\phi}{X} &= X^*, \qquad
 \grad{\phi}{X^*} = X  \;\equiv\; \gradLR{\phi}{X}^* \\ 
}$$
Applying these ideas to the above problem yields
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\a}{A} &= \frac 12\,
D^T\LR{H\odot\LR{L^T\CLR{L\LR{H\odot\LR{DA}}S-W}^{\c*}S^T}} \\
\grad{\b}{A} &= \frac 12\,
D^T\LR{M\odot\LR{K^T\CLR{K\LR{M\odot\LR{DA}}-Y}^{\c*}}} \\
}$$

Comment: Does the Frobenius definition and trace properties hold for complexe matrices ? Can you please provide me the source of trace properties, especially $C : \left( A B \right) = \left ( C B^T \right) : A$ ? because the second and the third seem to be wrong . Finally, why express $d\alpha$ on the form of $\nabla : dA$ to get the gradient expression ?

Comment: @MurDocHoøBs  $\:1)$ I've updated the answer for the case of complex matrices. $\:2)$ It is a simple exercise to verify the Frobenius products rearrangements from either of the two definitions provided (summation or trace). $\:3)$ Given the gradient of a scalar function with respect to a matrix, how else could you calculate its differential? The use of a Frobenius product is analogous to the use of a dot product in the vector case.

Comment: 1) Do you mean that in the complex case that if we let $\lambda = \alpha + \beta$ then $d\lambda = \left(\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial\mathbf{A}}+\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial\mathbf{A}}\right) : d\mathbf{A} + \left((\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial\mathbf{A}})^*+(\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial\mathbf{A}})^*\right) :d\mathbf{A^*}$. 2) When you put $\alpha = C:C$ then for $d\alpha = C:dC$ is it the frechet derivative ?